Check result in controller and write to variable
I use ASP.NET with MVC.
In my controller I make a query and send it to my view.
This works without any problems.
...
invoices = invoices.OrderBy(m => m.Datum).ThenBy(m => m.Rechnungsnummer);
return View(await invoices.ToListAsync());
        

I now also want to check in the controller before I call the view whether one or more data records were found.
If only one record was found, I would like to read one value from this dataset and use it in the controller for further queries.
When debugging the application I see that actually only one record was found.
invoices --> Ergebnisansicht --> [0]
There I have also my desired field "orderId".
Is it possible to read this value and write it into a variable?

I don't know, maybe this: var ergebnisansicht = invoices.SelectMany(x => x.Ergebnisansicht).FirstOrDefault() ?

Yes, it's possible.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

@Michal
Thanks for your input.
It put me on the right track.
Found the right solution for me.
    if (invoices.Count() == 1)
        {
            qry_order = (int)invoices.FirstOrDefault().orderId;
        }


The correct way is @paul-412 -
invoices = invoices.OrderBy(m => m.Datum).ThenBy(m => m.Rechnungsnummer).ToListAsync();

if (invoices != null && invoices.Count() >= 1)
{
   qry_order = invoices.FirstOrDefault().orderId;
}

We need to check count is greater than or equal to 1.
